# Vb.net button press automatically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there any way that a button on web page should pressed automatically when page loads?

I have following code on button to make rows of grid-view

```
 Dim nos() As Integer = New Integer((Convert.ToInt32(10)) - 1) {}
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (i < nos.Length)
            nos(i) = (i + 1)
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
        GridView1.DataSource = nos
        GridView1.DataBind()
        btnInsert.Visible = True
        btnInsert.Enabled = True
        GridView1.Focus()
```

I have also paste this code on page load event but when page loads it don't get textbox values to be inserted to database it only get values when this code is executed from button. That's why I was asking to button presses automatically when page loads

Comment: Cycle ?? That means another postback.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
a()
End Sub


Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
a()
End Sub


Sub a()
Dim nos() As Integer = New Integer((Convert.ToInt32(10)) - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While (i < nos.Length)
        nos(i) = (i + 1)
        i = (i + 1)
    Loop
    GridView1.DataSource = nos
    GridView1.DataBind()
    btnInsert.Visible = True
    btnInsert.Enabled = True
    GridView1.Focus()
End Sub
```